# Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on Docker on MAC M1 - Installation error arm64

Tags: docker, arm64, cloudera-cdh, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to setup "Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on Docker" on MAC M1

## Official Cloudera Installation directory

https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3.html

## Reference installation

https://javamana.com/2021/02/20210206191356735v.html

below is the configuration

Ram - 16gb

Rosetta2 Installed

Docker installed Mac M1

## Docker hub image link

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/hortonworks/sandbox-hdp/tags
```

## command used

```
docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1 --platform linux/amd64
```

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#This script downloads HDP sandbox along with their proxy docker container
set -x

# CAN EDIT THESE VALUES
registry="hortonworks"
name="sandbox-hdp"
version="3.0.1"
proxyName="sandbox-proxy"
proxyVersion="1.0"
flavor="hdp"

# NO EDITS BEYOND THIS LINE
# housekeeping
echo $flavor > sandbox-flavor


# create necessary folders for nginx and copy over our rule generation script there
mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d

# pull and tag the sandbox and the proxy container
docker pull "$registry/$name:$version"
docker pull "$registry/$proxyName:$proxyVersion"


# start the docker container and proxy
if [ "$flavor" == "hdf" ]; then
 hostname="sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com"
elif [ "$flavor" == "hdp" ]; then
 hostname="sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com"
fi

version=$(docker images | grep $registry/$name  | awk '{print $2}');

# Create cda docker network
docker network create cda 2>/dev/null

# Deploy the sandbox into the cda docker network
docker run --privileged --name $name -h $hostname --network=cda --network-alias=$hostname -d "$registry/$name:$version"

echo " Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait"
sleep 2
docker exec -t "$name" sh -c "rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;"


#Deploy the proxy container.
sed 's/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g' assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh > assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new
mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh 2>/dev/null

#check to see if it's windows
if uname | grep MINGW; then 
 sed -i -e 's/\( \/[a-z]\)/\U\1:/g' sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
fi
chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh 2>/dev/null
sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
```

**LOG**

```
➜  Documents sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
+ registry=hortonworks
+ name=sandbox-hdp
+ version=3.0.1
+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy
+ proxyVersion=1.0
+ flavor=hdp
+ echo hdp
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
70799bbf2226: Pull complete
40963917cdad: Pull complete
3fe9adbb8d7e: Pull complete
ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pull complete
7ea5917732c0: Pull complete
2d951411620c: Pull complete
f4c5e354e7fd: Pull complete
22ffa6ef360f: Pull complete
2060aa0f3751: Pull complete
ca01ba34744d: Pull complete
83326dded077: Pull complete
eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete
bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete
500cc770c4bd: Pull complete
0cb1decd5474: Pull complete
b9591f4b6855: Pull complete
f28e56086127: Pull complete
e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete
ec77967d2166: Pull complete
4fdcae170114: Pull complete
6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete
6a6ecc232709: Pull complete
ea845898ff50: Pull complete
02135573b1bf: Pull complete
cb0176867cd8: Pull complete
3c08321268fd: Pull complete
82e82a97c465: Pull complete
8aaaa48ed101: Pull complete
74b321ac2ac5: Pull complete
569da02c0a66: Pull complete
af40820407ef: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7b767af7b42030fb1dd0f672b801199241e6bef1258e3ce57361edb779d95921
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
docker.io/hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy
951bdea65c93: Pull complete
4b9047c5fbbb: Pull complete
773156407aae: Pull complete
d8524176841d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
docker.io/hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'
+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'
+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
++ docker images
++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ version=3.0.1
+ docker network create cda
ce52e1d04aa49c2da70dfd7405b95fc2e2184fed9625feaea0ddafb9ab5c361d
+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
3ab0f0281918fc10d008c93aa7a844302e974b696e00788df76cde779fdec46d
+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'
 Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait
+ sleep 2
+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ uname
+ grep MINGW
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
fbe0c31a680f51db9c91367df65493ea1cf874cc900466dd943824dc19bd9e74
➜  Documents
```

how to resolve the error

## I have tried performing some tweaks

adding the below line
--platform linux/amd64

still i encounter the same error

what is the work around to fix this issue ?

## Tweaks i have tried

before running the script i have tried adjusting the script by adding

```
# CAN EDIT THESE VALUES
registry="hortonworks"
name="sandbox-hdp"
version="3.0.1"
proxyName="sandbox-proxy"
proxyVersion="1.0"
flavor="hdp"
arch = arm64
platform = linux/arm64
```

## Deploy the sandbox into the cda docker network

docker run --privileged --name $name -h $hostname --network=cda --network-alias=$hostname -d "$registry/$name:$version" $platform

## option 1

arch = linux/arm64

## option 2

platform = linux/arm64

Comment: Can you check with another image that you can run amd64 images? e.g. latest ubuntu: `docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 ubuntu:latest uname -m`

Comment: Also - you might need to edit the script to include `--platform linux/amd64` switch every time `docker run` is run.

Comment: @michal - how to check ?

Comment: @michal - i have also tried the following 1) adjusted the script and included --platform linux/amd64 but not working

Comment: Like I wrote, try running `docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 ubuntu:latest uname -m` this should verify if rosetta is working correctly and you can run stuff compiled for amd64. I don't know how EXACTLY you modified the script, based on the log/console output you posted you've just run docker pull with platform switch before running the script while it should be added to every `docker run` command in the script.

Comment: @michal - i have included the script which i used to tweak

Answer (score 0):

First validate if Rosetta2 is configured correctly. You can test with alpine - very small linux docker container. Run:

```
docker run --rm -ti --platform linux/amd64 alpine:latest uname -a
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:d6d0a0eb4d40ef96f2310ead734848b9c819bb97c9d846385c4aca1767186cd4
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
Linux 35d1145cff16 5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 Linux
```

Now if that works you can modify scripts to run HDP. There are actually 2 scripts to modify.

### First

Open docker-deploy-hdp30.sh in a editor and modify following line:

```
docker run --privileged --name $name -h $hostname --network=cda --network-alias=$hostname -d "$registry/$name:$version"
```

To:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 --privileged --name $name -h $hostname --network=cda --network-alias=$hostname -d "$registry/$name:$version"
```

### Second

Open assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh in an editor & scroll to the bottom. There's docker run in line 204, add platform switch after it like this (the **backslashes** at the end of line are crucial!):

```
docker run --name sandbox-proxy --network=cda \\
--platform linux/amd64 \\
-v $absPath/assets/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \\
```

Now you are ready to run the first script (it triggers the other one).
After it executes `docker ps` should return 2 containers: sandbox-proxy and sandbox-hdp.

Comment: Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory.

Comment: please clarify - are you able to run alpine?

Comment: @michal- yes but when i ran all the steps during the installation i got the above error i will try to update the full log

Comment: any further suggestions ?

Comment: Can you check if any of the docker containers are actually running (with `docker ps` command)? I still believe the container is not running due to lack of the 'platform' switch. I don't see any edits in the question since Mar 16, so cannot even guess what's going on. The output log would be helpful, can you upload it to pastebin or github? Same goes for your modified scripts (please note that there are two that need to be changed).

Comment: i have tried to upload log it failed , i try to find a solution to share the log and i have also tried check docker ps the docker image ios running

Comment: please refer to the log below https://github.com/grgopidibd/bigdata2world/blob/main/log.sh

Comment: waiting for your answer